Access the site only if customer is logged in, Venia PWA
How to make if customer is not logged in, redirect to signed-in with availibility goto create account page?
Can anyone explain, please?
Don't know how to do that :)
I am new at Venia pwa, so if anyone can help me i will appreciate it :)
Also im new at react
